# Can't run GwtTestCase when updating GWT to 2.6.0

Tags: gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

After updating my `GWT` version to **2.6.0**, i got this error when running my old `GwtTestCase` :

```
[ERROR] The -out option is deprecated. This option will be removed in future GWT release       and will throw an error if it is still used. Please use -war option instead.
[INFO] <b>[ERROR] RunStyleHtmlUnit: Unknown browser name FF3, expected browser name: one of   [IE8, IE9, Chrome, FF17]</b>
[INFO] [ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.682 sec <<< FAILURE!
[INFO] testSerializeDeserialize(m6.sherpa.portal.widget.base.client.components.frame.GwtTestSerializer)  Time elapsed: 1.641 sec  <<< ERROR!
[INFO] com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitFatalLaunchException: Shell failed to start
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.getUnitTestShell(JUnitShell.java:732)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:705)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:421)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.run(GWTTestCase.java:247)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.test.MavenTestRunner.doRun(MavenTestRunner.java:105)
[INFO]  at junit.textui.TestRunner.start(TestRunner.java:183)
[INFO]  at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.test.MavenTestRunner.main(MavenTestRunner.java:63)
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to fix it is to just update your gwt-maven-plugin to 2.6.0 too.

In previous versions (up to and including 2.5.1), the `<htmlunit>` configuration property defaulted to `FF3`, but that value is no longer valid in GWT 2.6.0. gwt-maven-plugin 2.6.0 now defaults the property to `FF17`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GWT 2.6.0 no more supports FireFox v3. FF3 has been replaced with FF17.